# Flutter: What's the usage of the textEditingController provided to fieldViewBuilder in the Autocomplete widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, texteditingcontroller

What's the usage of the `textEditingController` provided to `fieldViewBuilder` in the `Autocomplete` widget? What can it be used for? Can it be used to modify or clear the content of the `TextField`?

```dart
Autocomplete<String>(
        fieldViewBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          TextEditingController textEditingController,
          FocusNode focusNode,
          VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
        ) {
          return TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            onChanged: (String value) {
              print('The text has changed to: $value');
            },
          );
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textEditingController` property provided to the `fieldViewBuilder` in the `Autocomplete` widget is used to control the text field. It can be used to modify or clear the content of the text field.

Comment: How? That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here, **fieldViewBuilder** used to Builds the field whose input is used to get the options for auto completions.

you can Pass the **TextEditingController** in **fieldViewBuilder**, to built here so that RawAutocomplete can **listen** for changes.

and **TextEditingController** is the controller for an editable text field. Whenever the user modifies a text field with an associated **TextEditingController**, the text field **updates** value and the controller notifies its **listeners**. Listeners can then read the text and selection properties to learn what the user has typed or how the selection has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

Now use this veriable

```
 controller: _textEditingController,
```

Now suppose on tap of a specific button or something you want to clear the textField, so what you can simply do is

```
onPressed: () {
         setState(() {
   _textEditingController.clear(); 
  });
 },
```

This will clean the text from the textField,
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
The **TextEditingController** is used for managing and controlling text input fields in Flutter apps. It allows you to read and set the text content of a TextField, listen to changes in the text, clear the text, and manipulate text selections.

Answer (score 0):

The `textEditingController` for the `fieldViewBuilder` callback is used inside of the `Autocomplete` widget to be able to build the options of the other `optionsBuilder` callback.

Because in the options builder callback you receive the `TextEditingValue` with the current text of your `TextField` which you provided the controller as a param.

Without this auto complete could not listen for changes to your text and would be unable to build options based on your text input.

And yes, you can change the value of the text editing controller and the change would also call the options builder again.

You can also see the behaviour in the following example:

```dart
  return Autocomplete<String>(
    fieldViewBuilder: (
      BuildContext context,
      TextEditingController textEditingController,
      FocusNode focusNode,
      VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted,
    ) {
      return TextField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        onChanged: (String value) {
          if (value.length == 5) {
            print("changed");
            textEditingController.text = "12345";
          }
        },
      );
    },
    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
      print("current text: ${textEditingValue.text}");
      return ["one", "two", "three"];
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textEditingController` provided to the `fieldViewBuilder` in the `Autocomplete` widget is used to control and manage the content of the TextField. It allows you to retrieve, set or modify the current text entered in the TextField.

Few operations can be done using `textEditingController`:

1. You can access the current value of the `TextField` using `textEditingController.text`.
2. You can set the content of the `TextField` using `textEditingController.text = "New Value"`.
3. You can clear the content of the TextField using `textEditingController.clear()`.
4. You can handle real-time updates and validations by listening to the changes made to the `TextField`'s content by registering an `onChanged` callback.

I believe this answers your question.